# A gap in a game theory derivation

Tags: convex-optimization, game-theory, economics

Consider an $n$-player game exerting effort to increase their probability of winning. Let $x_i$ denote $i$'s probability of winning and $e_i$ $i$'s effort:

$$x_i=\frac{e_i}{\sum_{j\in N}e_j}$$

$i$'s payoff is

$$u_i=v_i\frac{e_i}{\sum_{j\in N}e_j}-e_i$$

Then there exists a vector $\mathbf{e} \in \mathbb{R}_+$, where $x_i$ are the
winning probabilities that are a unique solution of the following convex optimization problem:

$$maximize \hspace{0.3cm} \sum_{i \in N}\hat{u}(x_i)$$
$$subject\hspace{0.1cm} to \hspace{0.3cm} \sum_{i \in N}x_i\leq1$$
 $$and\hspace{0.3cm}x_i\geq0$$

where $$\hat{u_i}=v_ix_i\bigg(1-\frac{1}{2}x_i\bigg)$$

Where did this $\hat{u_i}$ term come from?

---

$u_i$ can be rewritten as $$v_ix_i-\frac{x_i}{\sum_{j\in N}e_j}$$

But I can't see how $\hat{u_i}$ was arrived at. Any ideas?

---

Later is the following definition

$$\hat{u_i}=(1-x_i)u_i(x_i)+x_i\bigg(\frac{1}{x_i}\int_0^{x_i} u_i(z_i)dz\bigg)$$

Maybe this is useful for understanding the expression $\hat{u_i}$? But I can't figure out how this relates to the utility maximization problem.

Comment: If you're interested in seeing a picture of the derivation in the textbook, please upvote so I have enough points to paste a screeshot. Thanks!

Comment: I think that $\sum_i x_i = 1$ is one of the conditions since the total probability of a victor must be 1. (In some games everyone can lose,  so not strictly true)

Comment: @ErikKjellgren Thanks for your comment. This is the condition in the textbook (Contest Theory, Milan Vojnovic, pg. 174).

Comment: Can you derive the optimal $e_i$ for one player, given that the other $e_j$ are constant?

Comment: @LinAlg, I believe the maximization problem has a solution vector $\mathbf{e}$ that is all the equilibria.